# How to set curl_setopt for the all urls to download url with curl?

Tags: php, curl

There are many urls to be downloaded.

```
 foreach ($urls as $key => $url){
    $path = $path .strval($key);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data=curl_exec($curl);
    file_put_contents($path, $data);
    curl_close($curl);
    }
```

All the urls can be downloaded with the code,some statements executed for every url such as :

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Could the repeaded curl_setopt statements be simplified?How to simplify the code?

Comment: The easiest way is to put those lines inside a function and call it inside the for

Answer (score 0):

You are never executing your Curl request `curl_exec($curl);` So you are not even using Curl. If your code is working like this, you don't need any of those options. Then you can simplify your code to:

```
foreach ($urls as $key => $url){
    $path = $path .strval($key);
    $data=file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($path, $data);
    }
```

Comment: You mean if you are going to use `Curl`instead of `file_get_contents()`? It depends on what you want. Do you just download the content? Do you need the header and so on.

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);  `was deleted for my target.